# Can I set the isolation level in the connection string?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can I set the isolation level of all my SqlCommand ExecuteNonQuery calls to be read uncommitted?   (connecting to a SQL Server 2008 enterprise instance)

I am simply transforming static data and inserting the results to my own tables on a regular basis, and would like to avoid writing more code than necessary.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8aht5dh7.aspx

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, you cannot.

You need to explicitly define the isolation level when you start a transaction.

For more info on adjusting the isolation level, see the [MSDN documentation on the topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189542.aspx).

Comment: From what i have read there is not way of changing the default transaction isolation level
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ialonso/archive/2012/11/26/how-to-set-the-default-transaction-isolation-level-server-wide.aspx

Comment: "No, you cannot" is the correct answer, but I downvoted it due to "You can define a default transaction isolation level on a per-database level", which is not true.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot.

And there is No way of changing the default transaction isolation level.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ialonso/archive/2012/11/26/how-to-set-the-default-transaction-isolation-level-server-wide.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can set the isolation level in the SqlTransaction object, which is a property of the SqlCommand object.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction.isolationlevel.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
BEGIN TRAN
/* do stuff */
COMMIT
```

Comment: This isn't what I asked - I understand how to do it in SQL, but I have many pre-canned statements that need to run from a C# app, so I would like to set the isolation-level in code

Answer (score 0):

Note that ADODB allowed one to set the default isolation level for the connection, whereas ADO.NET will use the isolation level of the last committed transaction as the default isolation level (see the note in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ha4240h(v=vs.110).aspx).  See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189542%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 for details on setting the isolation level for various Microsoft database technologies.