# ASP.NET connections with READ UNCOMMITTED

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a web application and all of its queries begin with

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
```

Is there any way to create all connections with this isolation level? Can I implement this to connection pool in web.config or somewehere else?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303782/can-i-set-the-isolation-level-in-the-connection-string  and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471055/why-use-a-read-uncommitted-isolation-level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find this option in the properties of the database (if you are using SQL Server Management Studio) or alternatively using the [ALTER DB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522682.aspx) statement.

```
ALTER DB dname
SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT OFF
```

EDIT: Thanks to @Martin Smith, the command doesn't do what you want it to. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx) for more details (differences between Read Committed with Snapshot off and Read Uncommitted).

Comment: This doesn't do what the question asks for.

Comment: This will change the default on the database server to what he's requesting (which is to create all connections with the specified isolation level)

Comment: No it won't. It just changes how `READ_COMMITTED` is handled.

Comment: My apologies, I misunderstood the statement and have found a page which explains it in better detail. I'll update my posting.

Comment: I understand what you want to say. I can not change database's default isolation level so i should write this query to beginning of all of my queries. what a pity..

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do.

you need to explicitly define the isolation level when you start a transaction.